# Centering CellLabels

Tags: notebooks, cells, style

Is there a way to get cell labels to vertically center next to the input text? It always looks like the CellLabels are offset a bit too low:

[image]

Comment: Or too high.  Here I just set the magnification to 300%: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HvX1Z.png  Those cells have precisely one line.  There is no newline either before or after `Foo`.